# How do I run the preprocessor on local headers only?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, c-preprocessor, header-files

I want the preprocessor to read in the includes of local headers, but ignore the includes of system headers.  To put it another way, how do I get the preprocessor to skip over preprocessing directives of the form:

```
#include <h-char-sequence> new-line
```

but still process directives of the form:

```
#include "q-char-sequence" new-line
```

---

As a code example, observe the following file:

```
#include <iostream>     //system
#include "class_a.hpp"  //local
#include <string>       //system
#include "class_b.hpp"  //local

int main() {}
```

how can I get the output of the preprocessor to be:

```
#include <iostream>
class A{};
#include <string>
class B{};

int main() {}
```

---

Local include files may include other local include files, and the preprocessor would recursively bring them all in; much like it normally does.  It would still print all of the system file headers, but it would not bring in their contents.

---

on gcc, my call looks like this so far: `g++ -E -P main.cpp`, where `-E` stops after preprocessing, and `-P` excludes the generation of line markers.
I can't seem to find a flag that excludes the processing of system headers.

Comment: Does `-nostdinc++` work?

Comment: @sftrabbit it will still try to bring in the file, but it won't search the system directory.  It results in an error; something like: "iostream: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 28, accepted):

How much effort are you willing to go to?  There's an obnoxiously obscure way to do it but it requires you to set up a dummy directory to hold surrogates for the system headers.  OTOH, it doesn't require any changes in any of your source code.  The same technique works equally well for C code.

#### Setup

Files:

```
./class_a.hpp
./class_b.hpp
./example.cpp
./system-headers/iostream
./system-headers/string
```

The 'system headers' such as `./system-headers/iostream` contain a single line (there is no `#` on that line!):

```
include <iostream>
```

The class headers each contain a single line like:

```
class A{};
```

The contents of `example.cpp` are what you show in the question:

```
#include <iostream>     //system
#include "class_a.hpp"  //local
#include <string>       //system
#include "class_b.hpp"  //local

int main() {}
```

#### Running the C preprocessor

Running the C preprocessor like this produces the output shown:

```
$ cpp -Dinclude=#include -I. -Isystem-headers example.cpp
# 1 "example.cpp"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "example.cpp"
# 1 "system-headers/iostream" 1
 #include <iostream>
# 2 "example.cpp" 2
# 1 "class_a.hpp" 1
class A{};
# 3 "example.cpp" 2
# 1 "system-headers/string" 1
 #include <string>
# 4 "example.cpp" 2
# 1 "class_b.hpp" 1
class B{};
# 5 "example.cpp" 2

int main() {}
$
```

If you eliminate the `# n` lines, that output is:

```
$ cpp -Dinclude=#include -I. -Isystem-headers example.cpp | grep -v '^# [0-9]'
 #include <iostream>
class A{};
 #include <string>
class B{};

int main() {}
$
```

which, give or take the space at the beginning of the lines containing `#include`, is what you wanted.

#### Analysis

The `-Dinclude=#include` argument is equivalent to `#define include #include`.  When the preprocessor generates output from a macro, even if it looks like a directive (such as `#include`), it is not a preprocessor directive.  Quoting the C++11 standard ISO/IEC 14882:2011 (not that this has changed between versions AFAIK — and is, verbatim, what it says in the C11 standard, ISO/IEC 9899:2011 too, in §6.10.3):

> #### §16.3 Macro replacement
>
> ¶8 If a `#` preprocessing token, followed by an identifier, occurs lexically at the point at which a preprocessing directive could begin, the identifier is not subject to macro replacement.
>
> §16.3.4 Rescanning and further replacement
>
> ¶2 If the name of the macro being replaced is found during this scan of the replacement list (not including the rest of the source file’s preprocessing tokens), it is not replaced. …
>
> ¶3 The resulting completely macro-replaced preprocessing token sequence is not processed as a preprocessing directive even if it resembles one, …

When the preprocessor encounters `#include <iostream>`, it looks in the current directory and finds no file, then looks in `./system-headers` and finds the file `iostream` so it processes that into the output.  It contains a single line, `include <iostream>`.  Since `include` is a macro, it is expanded (to `#include`) but further expansion is prevented, and the `#` is not processed as a directive because of §16.3.4 ¶3.  Thus, the output contains `#include <iostream>`.

When the preprocessor encounters `#include "class_a.hpp"`, it looks in the current directory and finds the file and includes its contents in the output.

Rinse and repeat for the other headers.  If `class_a.hpp` contained `#include <iostream>`, then that ends up expanding to `#include <iostream>` again (with the leading space).  If your `system-headers` directory is missing any header, then the preprocessor will search in the normal locations and find and include that.  If you use the compiler rather than `cpp` directly, you can prohibit it from looking in the system directories with `-nostdinc` — so the preprocessor will generate an error if `system-headers` is missing a (surrogate for a) system header.

```
$ g++ -E -nostdinc -Dinclude=#include -I. -Isystem-headers example.cpp | grep -v '^# [0-9]'
 #include <iostream>
class A{};
 #include <string>
class B{};

int main() {}
$
```

Note that it is very easy to generate the surrogate system headers:

```
for header in algorithm chrono iostream string …
do echo "include <$header>" > system-headers/$header
done
```

JFTR, testing was done on Mac OS X 10.11.5 with GCC 6.1.0.  If you're using GCC (the GNU Compiler Collection, with leading example compilers `gcc` and `g++`), your mileage shouldn't vary very much with any plausible alternative version.

If you're uncomfortable using the macro name `include`, you can change it to anything else that suits you — `syzygy`, `apoplexy`, `nadir`, `reinclude`, …  — and change the surrogate headers to use that name, and define that name on the preprocessor (compiler) command line.  One advantage of `include` is that it's improbable that you have anything using that as a macro name.

#### Automatically generating surrogate headers

[osgx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/196561/osgx) [asks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20889460/how-do-i-run-the-preprocessor-on-local-headers-only#comment63755844_38163793):

> How can we automate the generation of mock system headers?

There are a variety of options. One is to analyze your code (with `grep` for example) to find the names that are, or might be, referenced and generate the appropriate surrogate headers.  It doesn't matter if you generate a few unused headers — they won't affect the process. Note that if you use `#include <sys/wait.h>`, the surrogate must be `./system-headers/sys/wait.h`; that slightly complicates the shell code shown, but not by very much. Another way would look at the headers in the system header directories (`/usr/include`, `/usr/local/include`, etc) and generate surrogates for the headers you find there.
For example, `mksurrogates.sh` might be:

```
#!/bin/sh

sysdir="./system-headers"
for header in "$@"
do
    mkdir -p "$sysdir/$(dirname $header)"
    echo "include <$header>" > "$sysdir/$header"
done
```

And we can write `listsyshdrs.sh` to find the system headers referenced in source code under a named directory:

```
#!/bin/sh

grep -h -e '^[[:space:]]*#[[:space:]]*include[[:space:]]*<[^>]*>' -r "${@:-.}" |
sed 's/^[[:space:]]*#[[:space:]]*include[[:space:]]*<\([^>]*\)>.*/\1/' |
sort -u
```

With a bit of formatting added, that generated a list of headers like this when I scanned the source tree with my answers to SO questions:

```
algorithm         arpa/inet.h       assert.h          cassert
chrono            cmath             cstddef           cstdint
cstdlib           cstring           ctime             ctype.h
dirent.h          errno.h           fcntl.h           float.h
getopt.h          inttypes.h        iomanip           iostream
limits.h          locale.h          map               math.h
memory.h          netdb.h           netinet/in.h      pthread.h
semaphore.h       signal.h          sstream           stdarg.h
stdbool.h         stddef.h          stdint.h          stdio.h
stdlib.h          string            string.h          sys/ipc.h
sys/mman.h        sys/param.h       sys/ptrace.h      sys/select.h
sys/sem.h         sys/shm.h         sys/socket.h      sys/stat.h
sys/time.h        sys/timeb.h       sys/times.h       sys/types.h
sys/wait.h        termios.h         time.h            unistd.h
utility           vector            wchar.h
```

So, to generate the surrogates for the source tree under the current directory:

```
$ sh mksurrogatehdr.sh $(sh listsyshdrs.sh)
$ ls -lR system-headers
total 344
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   20 Jul  2 17:27 algorithm
drwxr-xr-x   3 jleffler  staff  102 Jul  2 17:27 arpa
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   19 Jul  2 17:27 assert.h
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   18 Jul  2 17:27 cassert
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   17 Jul  2 17:27 chrono
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   16 Jul  2 17:27 cmath
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   18 Jul  2 17:27 cstddef
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   18 Jul  2 17:27 cstdint
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   18 Jul  2 17:27 cstdlib
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   18 Jul  2 17:27 cstring
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   16 Jul  2 17:27 ctime
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   18 Jul  2 17:27 ctype.h
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   19 Jul  2 17:27 dirent.h
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   18 Jul  2 17:27 errno.h
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   18 Jul  2 17:27 fcntl.h
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   18 Jul  2 17:27 float.h
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   19 Jul  2 17:27 getopt.h
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   21 Jul  2 17:27 inttypes.h
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   18 Jul  2 17:27 iomanip
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   19 Jul  2 17:27 iostream
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   19 Jul  2 17:27 limits.h
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   19 Jul  2 17:27 locale.h
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   14 Jul  2 17:27 map
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   17 Jul  2 17:27 math.h
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   19 Jul  2 17:27 memory.h
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   18 Jul  2 17:27 netdb.h
drwxr-xr-x   3 jleffler  staff  102 Jul  2 17:27 netinet
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   20 Jul  2 17:27 pthread.h
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   22 Jul  2 17:27 semaphore.h
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   19 Jul  2 17:27 signal.h
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   18 Jul  2 17:27 sstream
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   19 Jul  2 17:27 stdarg.h
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   20 Jul  2 17:27 stdbool.h
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   19 Jul  2 17:27 stddef.h
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   19 Jul  2 17:27 stdint.h
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   18 Jul  2 17:27 stdio.h
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   19 Jul  2 17:27 stdlib.h
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   17 Jul  2 17:27 string
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   19 Jul  2 17:27 string.h
drwxr-xr-x  16 jleffler  staff  544 Jul  2 17:27 sys
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   20 Jul  2 17:27 termios.h
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   17 Jul  2 17:27 time.h
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   19 Jul  2 17:27 unistd.h
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   18 Jul  2 17:27 utility
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   17 Jul  2 17:27 vector
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   18 Jul  2 17:27 wchar.h

system-headers/arpa:
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  22 Jul  2 17:27 inet.h

system-headers/netinet:
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  23 Jul  2 17:27 in.h

system-headers/sys:
total 112
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  20 Jul  2 17:27 ipc.h
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  21 Jul  2 17:27 mman.h
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  22 Jul  2 17:27 param.h
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  23 Jul  2 17:27 ptrace.h
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  23 Jul  2 17:27 select.h
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  20 Jul  2 17:27 sem.h
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  20 Jul  2 17:27 shm.h
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  23 Jul  2 17:27 socket.h
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  21 Jul  2 17:27 stat.h
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  21 Jul  2 17:27 time.h
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  22 Jul  2 17:27 timeb.h
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  22 Jul  2 17:27 times.h
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  22 Jul  2 17:27 types.h
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  21 Jul  2 17:27 wait.h
$
```

This assumes that header file names contain no spaces, which is not unreasonable — it would be a brave programmer who created header file names with spaces or other tricky characters.

A full production-ready version of `mksurrogates.sh` would accept an argument specifying the surrogate header directory.

Comment: How can we automize generation of mock system headers?

Comment: This is totally awesome. You scared me with your first sentence *"How much effort are you willing to go to?"* This solution is actually quite easy and so far totally perfect.

Comment: this `cpp -Dinclude=#include` part isn't working for me. `#include` is expanded, I cannot change the `include` word from `#include` (g++ (GCC) 6.2.1 20161010). Too bad as it was really a nice trick.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: That's curious.  Which platform are you on?  Which shell are you using?  It would be safer to use quotes around `-Dinclude="#include"` but it isn't necessary with most shells. Contact me if need so be; see my profile.

Comment: <shame> using windows :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Using plain Windows, or under Cygwin?  (Someone has to development on Windows; I'm just glad it isn't me).  I do once again have a Windows machine — Windows 10, quite a change from XP which is what I used last time I had a Windows machine — and use Cygwin on it.  I can experiment to see what I can find if need be.

Comment: I hate Cygwin... so plain Windows with kind of MinGW compiler... Don't be sad for me, between backslashes, stupid error messages, and carriage returns, it puts food on the table for me :)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The solution is amazing! I have one question. If the system header has macros or defines they won't be expanded in the output. I see no problems with macros (as they would be expanded later in the compilation). But I believe defines can be dangerous. Let's say your code has an `#ifdef` that depends on defines in the system header. The code will be emitted as if it had not been defined. Can you comment on that?

Comment: That's a correct observation, @rkioji.  What you do next — how you work around this limitation — depends on what your end goal is.  If you augment the surrogate system header(s) to also `#include` the original, you could probably arrange for suitable messages with file name and recognizable line numbers to be generated in the output (`#line 9998 "system-header.h"` before and `#line 9999 "system-header.h"` after the `#include <system-header.h>` which would at least give you markers that could be used to delete included material.  But all sorts of macro expansion will go on based on the header.

Comment: Anything much more complex and you're starting to write your own custom C preprocessor.  That could be done, of course, but it isn't an easy proposition.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Also, I wanted to add that if the code has any declaration with the name `include` this would lead to issues. For instance if the code declares a function called `void include(char*v)` the emitted code would be `void #include(char*v)`. This can be prevented by using a less common token in the surrogate headers. For instance `__sg_include__`. Then we would have `echo "__sg_include__<$header>"` in the `mksurrogates.sh` script and `-D__sg_include__=#include` in the GCC flags.

Comment: Do you make it a habit to use preprocessor keywords as ordinary identifiers (or tag names, structure member names, etc)? It's doable, but not exactly common.  There are quite possibly some other gotchas. I don't create macros in the namespace reserved for the implementation; I'm not implementing the implementation. Of course this is not a perfect solution!  It is a jury-rigged kludge that happens to work remarkably (unexpectedly) well. But if you want the job done properly (better than what this provides), you have to write code — non-negligible quantities of code — to do the job "properly".

Comment: This is an outstanding answer. One thing I'd add is that the `-P` flag on `cpp` or `gcc` can avoid the need for the grep to remove preprocessor line information.

Answer (score 9):

With clang you can do e.g.:

```
 clang -Imyinclude -P -E -nostdinc -nobuiltininc main.cpp
```

There does not seem to be a way to preserve the system `#include` lines it cannot find though.

This doesn't work for gcc, as its preprocessor will stop when using `-nostdinc` and it can't find an `#included` header file.

Comment: But there is no equivalent and nice way for gcc? :/ this is so basic...

Answer (score 1):

You can protect the system includes with a temporarily included comment, keep comments in the preprocessor output (`-CC`) and then remove the protectors again.

Something like:

```
sed -i 's%#include <%//PROTECTED #include <%g' $(find . -name '*.[hc]pp')
g++ -E -P -CC main.cpp -o new_main.cpp
sed -i 's%//PROTECTED %%g' new_main.cpp
```

Since you are modifying the source files, it might be a good idea to create a copy first and work on those copies instead. Plus some other details, but the above is the general idea you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could put a `#define SYSTEM_HEADERS 0` in a configuration header  and do it like this

```
#include "config.h" // the configuration header
#include "class_a.hpp"
#include "class_b.hpp"

#if SYSTEM_HEADERS // which is #if 0
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#endif
```

and when you want system headers you could make it `#define SYSTEM_HEADERS 1` which will include system headers.

Comment: I don't think this will work, as it won't put the `#include <iostream>` text in the output. Instead there will be nothing.