# How can I use "#" as a character in c++ preprocessor directives

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I want to redefine #include to a different word. I don't know if C++ preprocessing can do this, but I am trying:

```
#define import #include
#define io <iostream>

import io
```

This doesn't work obviously, so I'm just wondering if I can escape the "#" in the "import #include" statement to completely change it, but this would also require another run-through for the preprocessor I believe. Any input for this would be much appreciated.

Error output is "**Stray "#" found in statement...**" for anyone who wants to know the error.

EDIT:
I looked at the comments, and I now understand more how the c preprocessor works. I didn't really understand it before, but I think I found a work-around. The reason for this was to create a somewhat easy way to convert import statements from one language to include statements in c++. The language was of my own making, and yes, it does things that can't be done in other languages.

Comment: if you want to write phyton, why dont you write python? Seriously this is extremly obfuscating for no obvious gain. btw i dont think its possible

Comment: The preprocessor doesn't look for directives in the expanded output, even if the output looks like a directive.  Therefore, you cannot do what you are seeking to do.  In C11 (not necessarily identical with even C++11, but the functionality of the C and C++ processors is essentially the same), the standard says [§6.10.3.4 Rescanning and further replacement ¶4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.3.4p3): _The resulting completely macro-replaced preprocessing token sequence is not processed as a preprocessing directive even if it resembles one, but …_.

Comment: See also [How do I run the preprocessor on local headers only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20889460/how-do-i-run-the-preprocessor-on-local-headers-only) for a scenario where the rule about 'preprocessor directives cannot be created by macro expansion' was actively exploited.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Worth noting that `_Pragma` is not a preprocessor directive, so it can be generated by a macro. As far as I know that's the only case where a macro can generate the effect of a preprocessor directive (namely the effect of a `#pragma`).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: You're right — that's what the `but …` clause goes on to say: _but all pragma unary operator expressions within it are then processed as specified in 6.10.9 below._  There wasn't enough space in the comment for all of that.

Comment: But can I use "#" in a preprocessor statement as it's own character instead of a stringify operator?

Answer (score 3):

You can't redefine `#include` via facilities in the C++ language (including the preprocessor), sorry.

But you can preprocess the source code via any program, even one written in C++. Although my impression is that a scripting language is the most common choice. However, only do that for a very good reason.

For example, some people, including myself, think that the preprocessing in the Qt framework is Evil™. It's certainly unnecessary in modern C++, the language after C++11. But that framework predates modern C++.

Comment: Does that make QT a predator?

Comment: If it is, then it's a Qt predator. :)