# Using clang or g++/gcc to print preprocessed code without including files from system paths

Tags: c++, preprocessor

currently I'd like to debug my includes. To do this I want to get the preprocessed code, but without any system header files - just my own code.

I tried it with flag `"-E"` and `"-nostdinc"`. But then I get errors that for example `<string>` is missing. How to disable such preprocessing errors?

Comment: Why do you need to avoid system included headers?

Comment: GCC has a [script](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=contrib/uninclude;hb=HEAD) to replace standard header contents with `#include <...>`. It's aimed for compiler development, but maybe you can adjust it for your need.

Comment: Almost duplicate of [c++ - How do I run the preprocessor on local headers only? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20889460/how-do-i-run-the-preprocessor-on-local-headers-only) (except that in this case you want to delete the include instead of keep it unchanged)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(It's not really an answer - just a "hack")

To solve this I created a text file with all system headers by:

```
rem my GCC STL-PATH
cd Z:\usr\include\c++\10

dir /b > F:\DummySTL\files.txt
```

Then I executed the following line of code:

```
for /f "delims=" %F in (files.txt) do copy nul "%F"
```

This creates an empty text file for every line in the file.
Now I can call gcc or clang just with:

```
-isystem"F:\DummySTL"
```

Answer (score 2):

> Using clang or g++/gcc to print preprocessed code without including files from system paths

This is not easily possible with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/). Read about how to [invoke GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html).

But you could get *all* the preprocessed code using `g++ -C -E` and use some script (perhaps with [GNU gawk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/)) to remove the useless parts.

> currently I'd like to debug my includes.

I have the habit of generating *all the preprocessed code* and then use [GNU less](http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/) to look inside it. Disk space is cheap.

Alternatively, consider writing your own [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) doing what you need.

Answer (score 1):

> How to disable such preprocessing errors?

You could create a set of headers files with names matching the standard library headers. Put those headers in the include directory. Let the files be empty.

> Using clang or g++/gcc to print preprocessed code without including files from system paths

I can see two other approaches besides the empty header approach:

- Instead of using the full pre-processor of the compiler, write your own pre-processor that only does the subset of processing that you want.
- Or, write a post-pre-processor that removes the standard header content from the pre-processed result.

Comment: Oh, that is bad. Perhaps I could create just dummy files for all system header and use it as my system include path...

Comment: Do you have such a tool? (I need only include processing - I use macros only if there is no other way ...)

Comment: @BerndBaumanns Like one of the suggestions in second part of the answer? No.