# How do I suppress printing codes from system headers in gcc -E

Tags: c++, c, gcc, preprocessor, amalgamation

Basically, I need to amalgamate the source code into a single file . `gcc -E` almost does the job for me, except for the fact that I don't need to print the codes from system headers.
That is it should print my code as well as any codes from 3rd party library used but nothing from a system library.

I was wondering if I can tweak `gcc -E` such that it suppresses printing the codes from system headers.
In case that's already achievable by a combination of some other [options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html), you can mention that as well.

I have gone through this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62578619/865220). this hack doesn't work because the 3rd party libraries themselves call system headers which need to be suppressed as well.

Comment: As developers could imagine that thoe options are really needed only for compiler, toolchain and project tree debugging, there is no  really easy or direct options, which leave the result as a functional code and without system headers (problems often come from misconfigured, or header name conflict). What kind of xy problem such solution must solve?

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie okay so whats the hard option you can think of, something like forking the gcc preprosessor and modifying it ?

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie what do you mean by `xy problem` ? I just need to amalgamate  my source into a single file without any 3rd party dependency

Comment: @ishandutta2007 [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/1088098)

Comment: Actual problem is code amalgamation. Why? because I need my code in a single file and without any 3rd party dependency.

Comment: but why do you need it in a single file?

Comment: @NeilButterworth thats how my environment is. There I have many constrains to work. with.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I have tried [this](https://github.com/Viatorus/quom) amalgamator but it has many limitations, it's no where close to `gcc -E` but `gcc -E` has the problem of expanding system libraries as well which I dont want. if you go through this [ticket](https://github.com/Viatorus/quom/issues/52) you will understand in detail

Comment: better change your environment - you may be able to build an amalgamation of your code, but it will still be dependent on anly 3rd party code you call

Comment: @NeilButterworth LOL. thats not in my hand. Thats what the entire challenge is all about.

Comment: @NeilButterworth `gcc -E` expands in all the 3rd party refs very smoothly. no issues there. issue is it also expands the system libs which I dont want.

Comment: The discussions in this comments thread are not even at https://stackoverflow.com/a/62578619/865220 level yet. Guys First you have to be at that page to suggest me further enhancements.

Comment: the gcc solution wouldn't ONLY amalgamate code, it often would make it unreadable by unfolding all macro definitions and compiler-specific  macro names (which might be 
built-in into compiler's code or taken from some  built-in headers  which weren't mentioned). I'd pretty much started to write  a script which would unfold headers for me and remove duplicates (relatively easy) if I actually needed because that's a relatively unique task.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Readbility is not an issue for me since my code is small. It adds 2 comments(starting and ending) in the generated code to indicate  where from the block between those 2 comments is fetched. and that is nested as well. do you mean to parse the generated code based on those comments structure into a parse-tree?

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie But thats going  to be too much error prone. my point what if we could tweak the pre-processor itself to suppress those lines while printing based on where from its being fetched?

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie and then on my modied gcc preprocessor I can run something lilke `gcc -E -my_new_option`

Comment: have you looked at how sqlite manages its amalgamation?

Comment: @NeilButterworth I guesss [this](https://github.com/sqlite/sqlite/blob/master/tool/mksqlite3c.tcl) one Something wriiten in tcl. Mind you I dont need to amagamate the entire 3rd party libs . Since I only need to extract out few function out of the 3rd party libraries which my code calls. the final amagamated code will be small.

Comment: @NeilButterworth for example say my code is 100 lines long and it uses two 3rd party libs of 1M+ lines each now , the final amagamated code might be 100lines of mine plus few hundred lines from each of the 3rd party libs. so in total it may be less than 1K Lines which is no where close to 2M lines of the two libs. Hope you got how  my scenario is not like sqlite where they are flattening the entire library.

Comment: I was going to suggest using something like [pcpp](https://github.com/ned14/pcpp), but it sounds like you might need something more specialized if you also want to glue on and reduce the contents of 3rd party libraries to what you use (unless these have very heavy use of `#ifdef` in them to filter on).

Comment: I've never used `pcpp`. It looks like it has options for passing through `#include` directives it doesn't in its search paths (which you can just not pass in) without fiddling in its internals or API.

Comment: sorry I correct myself, preprocessor pulls in everything but amagamator like quom doesn't.

Comment: `Mind you I dont need to amagamate the entire 3rd party libs . Since I only need to extract out few function out of the 3rd party libraries which my code calls.`  this is non-trivial task provided that libraries today are interconnected  entities, not just "collection of functions"

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Have looked at open source tool like quom? No wonder it is non-trivial , which is why tools like quom are missing many scenarios? If you believe the way they have coded is the best was to go I may have to enhance quom to add support for more libraries that I work with.Do take a look and express your views on the best approach to go about it,

Comment: Quom simply stitches files  based on include. Not sure about missing scenarios, it seems to treat `#pragma once` (which is not standard C++)  just as line of code, which may result in incorrect amalgamation.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie So what are the tools you suggest for someone who needs to do it frequently? Doing manually takes hours even if you need to extract small logic from a large package . In python what I am doing is while running code without any amalgation I make a note of all file-names referred first. Then copy paste entire file content on top of my program for all those files. and then run my code with code coverage tool enabled. It gives me idea to what lines didint get referenced and can be deleted. I am not sure if I can do that in C++ that well.