# Is there a code preprocessing tool that would merge multiple user defined includes (an no system includes) into one file?

Tags: c++, include, preprocessor

I have a project consisting of multiple c++ files. I need to merge all of those files into one `main.cpp` file and send one file over the network. The recipient at the other end will compile and run the file:

```
gcc main.cpp
./a.out
```

Note that the recipient at the other end is a program, expecting only a single file and will not change his compilation instructions.

For example: suppose I have the following 2 files:

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>    

#include <my_utils.hpp>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v = GetVector();
    court << v.size() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

my_utils.hpp:

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>
std::vector<int> GetVector() {...}
void ProcessVector(const vector<int>& v) {...}
```

**Question**: is there a preprocessor command which would merge these two files into one to get the following:

```
// merged.cpp
// the recipient can compile and run this file

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> GetVector() {...}
void ProcessVector(const vector<int>& v) {...}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v = GetVector();
    cout << v.size() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

A standard preprocessor merges everything, including, e.g., a big amount of code that the `<vector>` contains. What I want is to merge multiple files into one, which would contain only my own defined functions.

**Optionally**: if I am not using `ProcessVector` in my main program, could a preprocessor exclude that function from the final merged file?

Comment: If you are on linux or similar you can use `cat file1 file2 > result` to concatenate many files into one. What's the purpose of this operation?

Comment: Please add some background information to the question why you want/need to merge the files.

Comment: @Human-Compiler sorry, that's not needed

Comment: @Bodo added my scenario explanation

Comment: Related: [How do I run the preprocessor on local headers only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20889460/how-do-i-run-the-preprocessor-on-local-headers-only)

Comment: If you have trouble with a build error, then please try to create a [mcve] and ask us about it directly instead. It's usually quicker and easier.

Comment: @TedLyngmo but `cat` command as is will also add all `#include <my_utils.hpp>` directives. The recipient will not have `my_utils.hpp` file at the other end.

Comment: Your use case looks strange. Why don't you send a TAR, ZIP or other archive or use a network protocol that can send multiple files? What is "the recipient"? A program? A person?

Comment: @Bodo, yes the recipient is a program, it does not read ZIP, etc. It just takes text file  `main.cpp`, compiles it and runs.

Comment: @mercury0114 And why is it designed in such a strange way?

Comment: @Bodo e.g. many online coding contests and platforms work in this way: `https://onlinejudge.org/` `https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/` etc.

Comment: And you want to automatically submit lots of combined projects to an online coding contest? A possible algorithm might be to create a list of all header files that are part of your project, `cat` all header files followed by all source files and remove all `#include` lines that reference one of the project's header files, e.g with `grep`. Of course, compiling all code combined to one big compilation unit may produce different results from compiling the modules separately. You might even get errors that would not occur with normal compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any preprocessor techniques to do this, but there are other possibilities. I read that you simply want to send a single compile-able `main.cpp` file for online coding competitions, so that's what I was working with.

If you have access to command-line tools, you could simply use `sed`. If you change all your local header includes to `#include "..."`, then you could do:

`sed '/#include ".*"/d' *.hpp *.cpp`

What this does is it prints all lines except lines that have `#include "..."` to `stdout`. All the `.hpp` files will be before all the `.cpp` files, so there shouldn't be any complications with prototypes. You can then just redirect this output to some file.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer. It seems that there is no tool that does it, so I will just have to write one myself.